# Difference between two ways to start activity with intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can someone please explain the difference between the two ways to start another activity?  I've tried both and they seem to work the same so I'm trying to figure out when to use one over the other if it matters at all.

I'm thinking that the latter example would allow **ActivityA**(this) to send an Intent to the Android system to start **ActivityC** from **ActivityB**?  Not really sure, I'm just guessing that if you changed the context of this to something else but I don't know why anyone would need to do this. Can someone please explain the pros and cons of one over the other and possibly an example?

```
Intent name = new Intent("android.intent.action.NAME") 

                vs 

Intent name = new Intent(this, NameActivity.class)
```

checked out:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: you forgot the "new" in the second form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please explain the difference between the two ways to start another activity?

The first uses an implicit `Intent`. There could be zero, one, or several activities on the system that all claim to support this `Intent` action.

The second uses an explicit `Intent`. There is precisely one possible match, since there is only one `NameActivity.class` in your project. Assuming that `NameActivity` is actually an activity, it is the one that will get started.

> so I'm trying to figure out when to use one over the other if it matters at all

The explicit `Intent` approach is primarily used for your own activities in your own app.

The implicit `Intent` approach is primarily used for inter-operability with other apps (e.g., launching a PDF viewer).

Comment: Oops I made a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Intent(this, NameActivity.class)` is syntax checked by compiler and can be refactored. So this allows compile time check of your code. `Intent("android.intent.action.NAME")` is just a string. When you change the class name or package this string is not modified so this can only be found by testing the app.

Calling inside your app the first way should be prefferred.